# Assigning order ID instead of Order Reference for each order in prestashop 1.7

Tags: php, symfony, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm using Prestashop 1.7
I have added a code that will generate the Order reference to match the order ID, it works great but the issue is that in case I have multi orders, both orders will be assigned same order reference.
For example:
If order ID is 118, the order reference will be 000000118 but if there are 2 orders, Order IDs will be assigned 119 and 120, but in order reference they will be seen as 000000119 0000000119

Here is my code:

```
public static function generateReference()
{
$last_id = Db::getInstance()->getValue('
SELECT MAX(id_order)
FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'orders');
return str_pad((int)$last_id + 1, 9, '000000000', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}

}
```

Comment: An order placed in a shop A of course will not have the same reference as other placed in a shop B, every new order generate a new ID and a new reference, you don’t need modify that method.

Comment: It's the same store shop, it's just if a cart contain multiple orders, each order will be assigned a different ID and i need the reference ID tobe unique as the order ID as well... how the code should be edited

Answer (score 0):

To force the reference to be the same as the id, instead of overriding the generateReference, you can override the add function to something like:

```
public function add($autodate = true, $null_values = true)
{
    $res = parent::add($autodate, $null_values);
    if($res){
        $this->reference = str_pad($this->id, 9, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $this->update();
    }
    return $res;
}
```

If you don't want to use an override, you can use a module, hooked to `actionObjectOrderAddAfter`, that is called by objectmodel with:

```
Hook::exec('actionObject'.get_class($this).'AddAfter', array('object' => $this));
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, however, it didn't work, I need to add something to my code which states, if order id =1, then reference is 1, but if 1 cart id, contains 2 orders, 2nd order will have reference 2 and third order will have reference 3 and so on

Comment: You want the reference to be the same as the order id or cart id? Or other?

Comment: @ZackTim I've made a small correction from $this->id_order to $this->id. Also, please check my previous comment.

Comment: please take a look at this screenshot from link https://prnt.sc/kl06x7 you will notice that only one of the order ID matches the order reference because the original cart contained multi items and each product will take an order reference, so how can I match the order Id with the order reference

Comment: @ZackTim That is weird behaviour. I'll try to simulate that (it's not simple). You could try to create a module and use the hook actionValidateOrder to do similar as above. Order is passed in $params['order'] to the hook.

Comment: Thanks, the thing is that I'm not a developper and i have very basic knowledge of php... your help is highly appreciated

Comment: @ZackTim why does one cart create several orders in yout store? I'm trying to enable warehouses in 1.7 and it seems to be disabled. Do you have any addon or module for that?

Comment: Yes i have an addon that split one cart that contains multi items into multi orders

Comment: @ZackTim Maybe the addon it's coded to use the same reference in each order. Would have to take a look at it. You can search the addon code for any mentio to order reference.

Comment: @ZackTim That seems to be only used to get the orders to display on confirmation (after adding all orders). Btw, it searches for orders with same reference, if you change the reference when creating it, this module wouldn't be able to find them to show the customer after confirmation. But it's not this function that creates the orders. There should be another function to add the orders.

Comment: I believe, the only function that generates the order reference is the one in Classes/Order/Order.php it's called generateReference

Comment: @ZackTim You can use any payment method? If so, the module might be overriding the validateOrder in PaymentModule. Or overriding the Order->add function. Or could use another hook. Can you share the functions names (classes also could help) in all of the addon files?

Comment: That function is in Order class. Would generate a sequential reference for all orders done normally.. Also, the override I answered with, would write another value (the same as the id. But it's neither case You get several orders (closed at the same time) with the same reference. And the addon searches for related orders using the reference. So the addon also might try to enforce the same order reference for all orders it adds.

Comment: Ok,can we even try to add a condition and observe the result?

Comment: @ZackTim What condition are you trying to do. The example in your question should work. Could cause error if 2 or more orders were created at the same time. Otherwise, it would result as you expected. The addon must be overriding this. You can try it on a fresh install of v1.7 or even 1.6 (to try with warehouses) that generate several orders if products are from different warehouses.

Comment: Hi, I'm feeling I'm getting nowhere, I reverse the code to the original public function to be : 

return strtoupper(Tools::passwdGen(9, 'NUMERIC'));

This will generate a 9 digits, but what I need is to do a check if the generated code existed, if it does, then it should add +1 to it, how to achieve it

Answer (score 0):

easy solution override :

```
    <?php    
    class Order extends OrderCore
    {       
        public static function generateReference()
        {
            $last_id = Db::getInstance()->getValue(' SELECT MAX(id_order) FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'orders'); 
            return str_pad((int)$last_id + 1, 5, '00000', STR_PAD_LEFT); 
        }
    }
?>
```

at last, you should delete `class_index.php` in `/var/cache/prod` to use it.